# how can I create an application for mobile phone with .JAR extension?

Tags: java, mobile, java-me

I Want to create a photo dictionary with .jar extension for mobile phones,what is the right tool or language for this purpose ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that you would want to write a so called [MIDlet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDlet) using [Java ME](http://java.sun.com/javame/index.jsp).

The proper tools include

1. The [Java SDK](http://java.sun.com/javase/index.jsp)
2. Eclipse together with a proper plugin such as [EclipseME](http://eclipseme.org/) (or another compliant IDE)
3. [The Sun Wireless Toolkit (WTK)](http://java.sun.com/products/sjwtoolkit/) which among other things contains an emulator)

A good step-by-step introduction to writing your first MIDlet can be found here:

http://www.autexier.de/jmau/dev/j2me/j2me.html

Comment: +1 for good links and information