# sending message to my cell using Java application

Tags: java, messaging

I have written an chat application in java, now I like to update my application whenever user registers my chat application I should get a sms on my cell.
I am not getting how should I start with messaging service. Let me know any ideas or links.

Thanks

Comment: you mean SMS when you say "message"? is this on an Android device, or are you aiming or good old Java ME?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is fully explained here (it even provides an example application available for download with source):

http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_Send_Text_SMS_in_Java_ME

Unless you've already know how to write Java MIDlets, I've explained the "startup"-steps here:

[how can I create an application for mobile phone with .JAR extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740862/how-can-i-create-an-application-for-mobile-phone-with-jar-extension/2740924#2740924)